# Bagging Classifiers

Tags: bagging

In **Bootstrap aggregating**, instances that have not been drawn (by resampling with replacement), e.g. end up for example in the test set.

However, in the bootstrap sample not every instance is unique. Do you keep **multiples** of the same instance?

If so, why does having the same information twice (or more), help reduce the variance component of the classifiers (ensemble)?